# Why there are so many ways to get the filter graph manager in directshow?

Tags: c++, directshow

Way 1:

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_PPV_ARGS(&pGraph));
```

Way 2:

```
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                    IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
```

What's the difference, why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IID_PPV_ARGS Macro**

Used to retrieve an interface pointer, supplying the IID value of the requested interface automatically based on the type of the interface pointer used. This avoids a common coding error by checking the type of the value passed at compile time.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330727(VS.85).aspx)